# How to parse objects that has a sealed class param in kotlin android development using Room?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, parsing, android-room

I have a Plant data class, that has a PlantType sealed class parameter.
I am using a Room local db, but when I try to parse it it fails. It works for other classes that has initializable class parameters.

Thanks for the help in advance.

**The error:** 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private com.tenyitamas.mylittlegarden.domain.util.PlantType() with no args

at com.tenyitamas.mylittlegarden.data.util.Converters.fromPlantsJson(Converters.kt:99)

// Comment: Converters.kt: 99 is the from json part of the Converters code, I included.

Plant.kt:

```
data class Plant(
    val type: PlantType,
    val upgrades: Upgrades
)
```

PlantType.kt:

```
sealed class PlantType {

    object Carrot : PlantType()
    object Tomato : PlantType()
    object Cucumber : PlantType()
    object Lettuce : PlantType()
    object Strawberry : PlantType()

    private companion object Constants {
        const val INITIAL_TIME_CARROT = 5_000L // 5s
        const val INITIAL_TIME_TOMATO = 6_000L
        const val INITIAL_TIME_CUCUMBER = 7_000L
        const val INITIAL_TIME_LETTUCE = 8_000L
        const val INITIAL_TIME_STRAWBERRY = 9_000L

        const val INITIAL_COST_CARROT = 10
        const val INITIAL_COST_TOMATO = 100
        const val INITIAL_COST_CUCUMBER = 1_000
        const val INITIAL_COST_LETTUCE = 10_000
        const val INITIAL_COST_STRAWBERRY = 100_000

        const val INITIAL_INCOME_CARROT = 10
        const val INITIAL_INCOME_TOMATO = 100
        const val INITIAL_INCOME_CUCUMBER = 1_000
        const val INITIAL_INCOME_LETTUCE = 10_000
        const val INITIAL_INCOME_STRAWBERRY = 100_000
    }

    val name: String
        get() {
            return when (this) {
                Carrot -> Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.carrot)
                Tomato -> Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.tomato)
                Cucumber -> Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.cucumber)
                Lettuce -> Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.lettuce)
                Strawberry -> Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.strawberry)
            }
        }

    val image: Bitmap
        get() {
            return when (this) {
                Carrot -> {
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources.getSystem(), R.drawable.ic_carrot)
                }
                Tomato -> {
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources.getSystem(), R.drawable.ic_tomato)
                }
                Cucumber -> {
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources.getSystem(), R.drawable.ic_cucumber)
                }
                Lettuce -> {
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources.getSystem(), R.drawable.ic_lettuce)
                }
                Strawberry -> {
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources.getSystem(), R.drawable.ic_strawberry)
                }
            }
        }

    val initialTime: Long
        get() {
            return when (this) {
                Carrot -> INITIAL_TIME_CARROT
                Tomato -> INITIAL_TIME_TOMATO
                Cucumber -> INITIAL_TIME_CUCUMBER
                Lettuce -> INITIAL_TIME_LETTUCE
                Strawberry -> INITIAL_TIME_STRAWBERRY
            }
        }

    val initialCost: Int
        get() {
            return when (this) {
                Carrot -> INITIAL_COST_CARROT
                Tomato -> INITIAL_COST_TOMATO
                Cucumber -> INITIAL_COST_CUCUMBER
                Lettuce -> INITIAL_COST_LETTUCE
                Strawberry -> INITIAL_COST_STRAWBERRY
            }
        }

    val initialIncome: Int
        get() {
            return when (this) {
                Carrot ->   INITIAL_INCOME_CARROT
                Tomato ->   INITIAL_INCOME_TOMATO
                Cucumber -> INITIAL_INCOME_CUCUMBER
                Lettuce ->  INITIAL_INCOME_LETTUCE
                Strawberry -> INITIAL_INCOME_STRAWBERRY
            }
        }
}
```

Converters.kt

```
@TypeConverter
    fun fromPlantsJson(json: String): List<Plant> {
        return jsonParser.fromJson<ArrayList<Plant>>(
            json,
            object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Plant>>(){}.type
        ) ?: emptyList()
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toPlantsJson(plants: List<Plant>): String {
        return jsonParser.toJson(
            plants,
            object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Plant>>(){}.type
        ) ?: "[]"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PlantType` sealed class has only objects inside it. You can just use an enum for this.

```kotlin
enum class PlantType {
    Carrot, Tomato, Cucumber, Lettuce,  Strawberry
}
```

And most likely your `jsonParser` will be able to serialize this enum.

**Edit:** In your edited question, you just have added some new `val`s inside the `PlantType` class all of which has custom getters which return value depending upon the `PlantType`. You can still replace it with the enum and put those `val`s as extensions on `PlantType`.

For example,

```kotlin
enum class PlantType {
    Carrot, Tomato, Cucumber, Lettuce,  Strawberry
}

val PlantType.name: String
        get() {
            return when (this) {
                Carrot -> Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.carrot)
                Tomato -> Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.tomato)
                Cucumber -> Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.cucumber)
                Lettuce -> Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.lettuce)
                Strawberry -> Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.strawberry)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I edited the original post with the rest of my sealed class

Comment: I have edited the answer. See if it meets your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it and get back to you. But at first sight this might be the solution :)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. That was the solution.

Comment: What would be a solution for this if PlantType's would need multiple nested objects inside?

Comment: Can you provide an example for the case you are mentioning? It might be a better idea to ask a new question for this.